# How to find my activity bar in vs code I wanna download live server

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried everything, shortcut keys, search bar, view does not have appearance. I am not able to find my activity bar. If there is a list of shortcuts please share I will try again. I am trying to install live server but I am not able to do that also tried going to it via the links on Microsoft websites. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `View -> Appearance -> Show Activity Bar` to enable the activity bar

or try `ctrl+shift+p -> type "setting" -> type '"workbench.activityBar.visible": true' in setting.json`[image]

Comment: There is no appearance in my view drop down

Comment: @SamyakVermani I have updated my answer with another method, hope this method can help you solve this problem

Comment: still not working, cant seem to install liver server either